# How do i make a netbean's GUI pop up when i run it

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

When i make a GUI on netbeans, and i hit run on the top, nothing happens. it just says "build successful". i dont know how to make it do this. any help would be great! thanks

ps: i've googled it and I cant find anything on the subject.

pss: i just remembered. i saw onetime when i was at a friends house, he has the same problem. all he had to do was add a code somewhere to make it pop up. idk what or how, but thats what i remember. idk if it will help though.

Comment: What if you just run the current file instead of the whole project by pressing `shift-f6`?

Comment: Not so fast, @Hover...  Does your class have a `main` method?  Please post some code so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: @Paul: ;) but of course. +1. I shouldn't even be answering this since I'm mainly an Eclipse user and shudder at the thought of a seeing NetBean's-generated GUI code. Get ready for some super-ugly layout code.

Comment: @Hover, I'm a NB guy and I love it, but yeah, NB's auto-generated GUI code and build files are not fit for human consumption. However, I'd rather deal with NB's GUI code than Eclipse's GUI...but that's off topic :)

Comment: yes. i just went with the default code. it has a main class. i works with `shift-f6` but doesnt with just `f6`... ill add some code

Comment: its not letting me add the code by editing the post because the `` thing is glitching out... and i cant comment with it. but i have all the default parts. i just need to know why it wont run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. all i needed to do was delete the current main class which was a useless .java file and set my main class as the jframe file! thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create an instance of your GUI (let's say it's called, GUIDemo) in your main class and then you set it visible. You'd do this like this:

```
GUIDemo gui = new GUIDemo();
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Note that not all versions of Netbeans automatically create that constructor, you would have to write it yourself. In the source code for GUIDemo, you'd add this constructor:

```
public GUIDemo()
{
    initComponents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be happened that your main project setup was not correct.Right click your project from left side project explorer pane and select **set as main project**.